# How to prevent the next check function when I already got false in yup?

Tags: javascript, yup

I using yup to validate my input against the schema.

The `name` is empty array. should failed in min function. but anyway its continue to the test function.

How to prevent that? if it's failed in `min` it shouldn't continue to the next function.

Is it possible to do it in yup?

To be clear: the name is `[]` so it failed in `min` function. why continue to check the `test` function?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-neumann-3uedh?file=/src/index.ts)

```
import * as yup from "yup";

console.clear();

let schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.array().min(1).test('x', 'y', (v) => {
    console.log({ v });

    return true;
  })
});

// check validity
schema
  .validate({
    name: []
  }, { abortEarly: true })
  .then((valid) => {
    console.log({ valid });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log({ e });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems not to be possible according to [this](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1311#issuecomment-805834729) issue:

> tests are run in parallel, so there aren't "previous checks" as they are all happening at the same time for a schema.

You can just control with the `abortEarly` option how many errors you're going to collect in ValidationError: whether all of them (`abortEarly: false`) or just the first one (`abortEarly: true`). But that will not prevent all your validation functions to be ran.

Comment: I set it to abortEarly, still happens. the `abortEarly` is about in object keys and not key-validation-functions.

Comment: It still happens because, as I wrote, there is no way to prevent all your validation functions to be ran. With `abortEarly` you can control how many errorrs you're going to collect in ValidationError. Let's say your `test()` returns `false`: with `abortEarly:false` you'll find two items in `ValidationError.errors` (corresponding to `min()` and `test()`). With `abortEarly:true` you'll find only the first one to fail.

Comment: I edited the part about `abortEarly` in my answer, I can see now why it was misleading/incorrect.